How to prevent browser back button from being spammed
The following code works well if I click on the browser back button without spamming it, But if I spam the browser back button it goes back and I am taken away from the page that I was on.
Is there a way to prevent the browser back button from allowing the user to go back or if it is possible to disable the button itself?
useEffect(() => {
        // Handle browser back button
        const handlePopState = (event: PopStateEvent) => {
            if (somedata === 'practice') {
                showPracticeCloseConfirmation();
            } else {
                showMainTestCloseConfirmation();
            }
            // Prevent further navigation
            window.history.pushState({ appControlled: true }, '', window.location.href);
        };

        // Check if the page was reloaded
        const navigationEntry = performance.getEntriesByType('navigation').find(
            (entry): entry is PerformanceNavigationTiming =>
                (entry as PerformanceNavigationTiming).type !== undefined
        );
        if (navigationEntry?.type === 'reload') {
            // If the page is refreshed, replace the initial state
            window.history.replaceState({ appControlled: true }, '');
        } else {
            // For normal navigations, push a new state
            window.history.pushState({ appControlled: true }, '');
        }

        // Check if session state exists after reload and restore it
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('appState') && !state) {
            const storedState = sessionStorage.getItem('appState');
            if (storedState) {
                const parsedState = JSON.parse(storedState);
                setState(parsedState);
            }
        }

        // Attach the popstate event listener
        window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

        // Cleanup the event listener on component unmount
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        };
    }, [somedata, state]);


But why? You are breaking a fundamental mechanic of the web: the back button. This is going to cause you massive headaches and you probably won't win because you are fighting the browser. Don't do it, reconsider why you got into this position in the first place where you are going to break a fundamental thing of the web that has existed for 30 years now.
